# I need to capture month and year for the string, <a href="/statement.php?month=07&amp;year=2018"> ,

Tags: jmeter

For this task i have to capture not only month and year but also the entire string starting from i.e < a href
using dummy sampler and regular expression extractor
can u pls suggest me

Answer (score 1):

You can go for something like:

```
<a href="(/statement.php\?month=(\d+)&amp;year=(\d+))">
```

This will result in the following matches:

```
Match[1][0]=<a href="/statement.php?month=07&amp;year=2018"> 
Match[1][1]=/statement.php?month=07&amp;year=2018
Match[1][2]=07
Match[1][3]=2018
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regular Expressions Demo]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Regex Tutorial: Use Parentheses for Grouping and Capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: for the above task how to  Create a two variables , assign month as one variable and year as one variable  and Pass these assigned variables into another request.using bean shell post processor and dummy sampler .